# Deterministic optimal call time

Tags: options, stochastic-processes, american-options, call

Consider a American Option on a linear payoff i.e., if called at time $T$, it pays off $S(T)$, the stock price. Is the optimal call time of such an option determinsitc? Is there an intuition to the same; as in why linearity forces a deterministic call time?

Comment: Does the stock pay dividends?

Comment: You can assume dividends are proportional rather than cash; or none at all so that its just a drift adjustment